# Проблема eval()

Tags: массивы, php, eval

```
$text = "array('lol' => 123)";
eval("\$text = \"$text\";");

echo $text['lol']; // выдаёт символ "a", вместо 123. В чём проблема?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

потому что вторая переменная в eval она в кавычках, и получается на выходе стринг обычный а не массив:

```
$text = "array('lol' => 123)";
eval("\$text = {$text};");

echo $text['lol'];
```

Так будет работать как надо